# Magento invoice custom text not aligning

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, zend-framework, create-invoice

Hi guys I am attempting to edit the invoices of magento but I cannot get my custom text to align with the totals on the right. I would like the headings 'important' and 'Pay us by bacs' to be inline with the subtotal heading of the totals.

[image: Result of my efforts thus far]

My function code in abstract.php:

```
public function insertBankInfo(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text)
{
    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Html('#447282'));
    $this->_setFontBold($page, 9);
    $page->drawText($text, 285, $this->y += 34.5, 'UTF-8'); 
    $page->drawText("IMPORTANT:", 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
    $text = $this->y -= 15;
    $page->drawText("When remitting your payment, please quote your account number and our INVOICE NUMBER AS SHOWN above", 35, $this->y += 4, 'UTF-8');
}
```

My code in invoice.php:

```
$this->insertBankInfo($page, Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pay US BY BACS'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In invoice.php I moved the line above the totals:

```
        $this->insertBankInfo($page, Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pay US BY BACS'));
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
```

Then I changed line 662 in abstract.php to :

```
     $this->y += 12;
```